# Sorting a range (with no duplicates) in C++, is std::vector and std::sort faster than std::set?

Tags: c++, performance, sorting

I have a sequence of double (with no duplicates) and I need to sort them. Is filling a `vector` and then `sort`ing it faster than `insert`ing the values in a `set`?

Is this question answerable without a knowledge of the implementation of the standard library (and without a knowledge of the hardware on which the program will run) but just with the information provided by the C++ standard?

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

std::uniform_real_distribution<double> unif(0,10000);
std::default_random_engine re;

int main()
{
    std::vector< double > v;
    std::set< double > s;
    std::vector< double > r;
    size_t sz = 10;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        r.push_back( unif(re) );
    }

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        v.push_back(r[i]);
    }
    std::sort(v.begin(),v.end());

    for(size_t i = 0; i < sz; i++) {
        s.insert(r[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://bigzaphod.org/set.vs.vector/

Comment: @0A0D at a first glance it seems to me that http://bigzaphod.org/set.vs.vector/main.cpp does not sort the vector and it is most interested in looking up for a value inside the container.

Comment: I would suggest this reading : [Why you shouldn't use set (and what you should use instead)](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=why%20you%20shouldn't%20use%20set%20(and%20what%20you%20should%20use%20instead)&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CCUQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Flafstern.org%2Fmatt%2Fcol1.pdf&ei=KjhFT6fnNcnPrQf4pfjXDw&usg=AFQjCNEOAgURQSrd8Z8uBzP3m6l6Yd3qwA&sig2=uQqpzi4XxcVx0uXVY5UlqA)

Comment: @Nawaz: he missed the point though. As any node-based container, the real killer feature of `set` (and co) is the stability of their elements' addresses during insertion/removal. If not for that, we would use B+ Trees.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the C++ standard, all we can say is that they both have the same asymptotic complexity (`O(n*log(n))`).

The set may be faster for large objects that can't be efficiently moved or swapped, since the objects don't need to be moved more than once. The vector may be faster for small objects, since sorting it involves no pointer updates and less indirection.

Which is faster in any given situation can only be determined by measuring (or a thorough knowledge of both the implementation and the target platform).

Answer (score 2):

The use of vector may be faster because of data cache factors as the data operated upon will be in a more coherent memory region (probably).

The vector will also have less memory overhead per-value.

If you can, reserve the vector size before inserting data to minimize effort during filling the vector with values.

Comment: reserving space for the vector would be a bit "unfair" for the set, or no?

Comment: @uvts_cvs: not at all, use what you got.

Comment: How is that unfair? It's a distinct advantage of the vector.

Comment: @uvts_cvs Uhm no, as that's one of the advantages vector offers over set. You don't want to bias the outcome towards set, don't you?

Comment: @ChristianRau No, I do not want to bias the outcome :-)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of complexity both should be the same i.e, nlog(n).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is not trivial. If you have 2 main sections in your software: 1st *setup*, 2nd *lookup* and *lookup* is used more than *setup*: the sorted `vector` could be faster, because of 2 reasons:

1. `lower_bound` `<algorithm>` function is faster than the usual tree implementation of `<set>`,
2. `std::vector` memory is allocated less heap page, so there will be less page faults while you are looking for an element.

If the usage is mixed, or *lookup* is not more then *setup*, than `<set>` will be faster. More info: [Scott Meyers: Effective STL, Item 23](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Effective-STL-Specific-Professional-Computing/dp/0201749629).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "heap page". Even if you even happen to be on an architecture where the concept of a memory page makes sense, nothing says the vector must be smaller than a page...

Comment: @BillyONeal: true. I modify my anser.

Answer (score 0):

Since you said sorting in a range, you could use `partial_sort` instead of sorting the entire collection.
If we don't want to disturb the existing collection and want to have a new collection with sorted data and no duplicates, then `std::set` gives us a straight forward solution.

```
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    int arr[] = { 1, 3, 4, 1, 6, 7, 9, 6 , 3, 4, 9 };
    vector<int> ints ( arr, end(arr));
    const int ulimit = 5;
    auto last = ints.begin();
    advance(last, ulimit);
    set<int> sortedset;
    sortedset.insert(ints.begin() , last);

    for_each(sortedset.begin(), sortedset.end(), [](int x) { cout << x << "\n"; });
}
```